# no templates for ADO.NET in visual studio 2015 rc

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, visual-studio-2015

i am learning asp.net 5 and MVC 6! i created a web project

like this picture[image: create project]
after that `right clicked on Models folder -> add new item`  but there is no ADO.Net templates here ( in VS 2013 it exist ). here is a picture :
[image]
this problem is only for web project, i created a Windows Application and added new item there was ADO.NET templates. here is picture :
[image]
how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Create a class library in your solution, add it in there, and reference it from your other project. You shouldn't keep your DA in your web project anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure where you're getting your information from, but that is incorrect. You should keep your models separate. There are articles that are misleading, confusing Models and ViewModels. Your ViewModel (Models folder in MVC) should really just be a wrapper for your actual Entity (in your case ADO Entity) - which should be referenced in a separate project, which will be a Class Library. @Oli

Comment: Is there a NUGET reference to EF?

Comment: @SteveGreene EntityFramework comes as a reference out of the box with Visual Studio. Since it is a MS managed library, it would not be in NuGet.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Can't say for sure with 2015 which is probably even more stripped down, but in VS 2013 EF, MVC, Web API are all nuget packages, https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework

Comment: @SteveGreene yes , i installed 6.1.3

Comment: still problem exist?

Answer (score 4):

Anyone having the same problem on any kind of project (like it was my case) and unable to open existing EDMX, be careful when you install VS 2015, and make sure to check the box saying "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools".

I had not (we only use MySQL), and it is required for the Entity Framework designer, whatever connector you're using.

Comment: when I run the setup again, cannot see the option anymore, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

there is no support for edmx format in mvc6. 
Pre version mvc5 would have got but mvc 6 doesnt. 
Good luck